# Signal level estimation, matlab

Tags: matlab, filters

Three methods of estimating maximum signal level at a node:

1. Worst Case Min-Max (L1-Norm)
2. Mean Square (L2-Norm)
3. Frequency Domain (Linfinity-Norm)

[image]

In matlab i found the code for L1, L2

> ```
> Hfull=[h(r,:),conj(fliplr(h(r,2:end-1)))];
> L1(r)=sum(abs(ifft(Hfull)));
> L2(r)=sqrt(mean(Hfull.*conj(Hfull)));
> ```

For Linf is correct the below?:

Linf(r)=max(abs(Hfull));

Comment: The $L_1$ norm is usually called the "City Block distance" rather than "Min-Max".  The $L_\infty$ norm is usually called min-max.  Your definition of the $L_\infty$ norm looks fine, but your implementation takes the maximum of value of $h_{s,r}(k)$ as $k$ varies rather than the maximum of $H_{s,r}(\nu)$ as $\nu$ varies.

Comment: Is there a possible way from Hfull to take the correct value, or i need to do other arrangements?

Comment: `Hr = fft(Hfull); LInf(r) = max(abs(Hr))` would be my guess. Now that I look at it, your definition of `L1` is a little suspect, too... I see no reason to take the `ifft`; `Hfull` seems to already be in the time domain.